# How do I use a variable of type Type as a Type?

Tags: c#

I have a foreach loop running on a list of types. Passing in a variable of type Type as a Type fails outright. Based on similar questions seen on this site, I wrote up a reflection-powered solution but this fails at runtime. I do not know how to proceed from this point.

```cs
foreach (Type defType in GenDefDatabase.AllDefTypesWithDatabases())
{   
    // Compile Error: 'defType' is a variable but is used like a type
    DefDatabase<defType>.ResolveAllReferences(); 
    // Runtime Error: System.ArgumentException: The method has 0 generic parameter(s) but 1 generic argument(s) were provided.
    //   at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.MakeGenericMethod (System.Type[] methodInstantiation) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
    typeof(DefDatabase<>).GetMethod("ResolveAllReferences", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static).MakeGenericMethod(defType).Invoke(null, null);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use reflection to call a generic method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232535/how-do-i-use-reflection-to-call-a-generic-method)

Comment: @just-my-name: the problem is that they are trying to call a generic method, even though the method is _not_ in fact generic. See my answer below.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I see, the type itself is generic, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this statement:

```
typeof(DefDatabase<>).GetMethod("ResolveAllReferences",
    BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static).MakeGenericMethod(defType).Invoke(null, null);
```

You are trying to make a generic method. But the thing that's generic is the *type*, not the method. You should be calling `Type.MakeGenericType()` instead:

```
typeof(DefDatabase<>).MakeGenericType(defType).GetMethod("ResolveAllReferences",
    BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static).Invoke(null, null);
```